# Getting length of firestore snapshot in flutter returns "Instance of Future<int>"

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to return the length of items returned by a query using the `.length.toString` method and storing the String response in an variable

```
final String numberOfChildren = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("children")
        .where("parentUID", isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .length
        .toString();
```

When I try to use the variable `numberOfChildren` in a Text widget like
`Text('Children $numberOfChildren'),` 
It returns
[image]

I thought it would return a string, why does it do this?

Edit

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await for it first:

```
final String numberOfChildren = await FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection("children")
.where("parentUID", isEqualTo: uid)
.get().then((result)=>results.docs.length.toString());
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to put it a an async function, because when I tried this, I couldnt access the variable from inside a function

Comment: Definitely yes.

Comment: How do I access the variable from inside a function

Comment: You use it as a function, or second option is via stream\future builder.

Comment: You can't use inside your build method like this. Change it into a stateful widget, or as I said above, a future builder. If you decide to use a stateful widget, you need to set state after the function returns a value, to update your UI.

Comment: It is a stateful widget

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236300/discussion-between-ninjasauce-and-huthaifa-muayyad).